# Agricola Card Organization Solutions?

Tags: agricola, storage

So I expect most of us Agricola nuts have already got a tackle box for all the meeples and counters.  But now that I own the base set, Farmers of the Moor, the Gamers Deck, AND the Goodies, I'm finding the cards pretty unmanageable too.

The base set comes with E, I, K and Z decks (for both Minor Imps and Occupations), plus the Occupations have to be subdivided into 1+, 3+ and 4+ player sets, if like us you often play with fewer than 4 players.  Farmers of the Moor has Minor Improvements with different backs, subdivided into (confusingly) another E deck and an F deck.  The Gamers deck adds a G deck, and the Goodies brings the L, Cz, Oe and X decks!  (All of these including Occupations suitable for different minimum numbers of players.)

The temptation is just to give up and mix them all up together, apart from the Farmers of the Moor improvements, and sorting the Occupations by minimum player number; but maybe there's a better way.  Can anyone recommend a method of boxing and dividing Agricola cards so we can quickly play with any subsets of cards we choose?  Are there any commercially available card boxes that are the perfect size for Agricola cards, have enough capacity to accommodate my growing collection, and preferably come with dividers too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use zip-lock bags for nearly all my boardgames that have cards. Tuck-boxes are better, admittedly, but zip lock bags work much better than magic tape or rubber bands. I typically use the "snack bag" or "sandwich bag" size of zip-lock baggies you can get in the grocery store, because they're cost effective in that format. Rectangular shaped ones are probably better, but the price per unit and convenient availability of them is not so good. Agricola in particular, I seem to remember, came with a bunch of rectangular shaped baggies (or I got a supply of them from somewhere at the same time as the game) so it, in particular, has all the decks separated by type and in rectangular zip-lock baggies sized roughly appropriate for that size of card.

Answer (score 2):

Go to boardgamegeek.com and print and construct the custom tuck boxes for each deck.  Worked great 4 me.  Or, put the game away and just play online at play-Agricola.com

@Monica rubber banding you cards is sac-religious to us ultra board game dorks

Comment: I like the notion of tuck-boxes better than zip-lock baggies, but zip-lock baggies are just so much more convenient for those of us who are even a wee bit lazy. On the other hand, tuck boxes might make an awesome summer-craft project for my daughter... 8)

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to commit sacrelige. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This will be a little too big, but they make "file boxes" for index cards, and also dividers.  The boxes I've seen hold around 500 cards.

We don't have the expansions so our problem is simpler than yours, but we just use rubber bands to separate groups of cards, and when playing with an unusual-for-us number of players we just dig through to find the right ones.

Comment: Why not use the file boxes, but add index cards as dividers to separate decks/types of cards? That way you wouldn't have to use rubber bands ...

Comment: Currently everything fits in the game box (because we don't have any expansions), so adding the file box would add something else to carry around.  Once things no longer fit in the box, though, that's not a concern.

Comment: I find that rubber bands are not awesome. They eventually break down, leave gunk on the cards, and they can indent the edges of the card if they're not properly sized.

Comment: True, you have to use the right size bands and monitor their conditions.  We buy them in quantity and replace liberally.

Answer (score 1):

I store my cards in the bottom end of the box so the long sides sit on bottom, the short end on the bottom end and the face/back to the side of the box and have made temporary dividers for deck, but you could organize them however.

I then constructed a wooden frame to hold them all there. I don't have goodies but I have G, WM and fotm all in the base box. The only problem with this solution is the box doesn't quite close flush